# Where would I add a for loop? Stock Transaction

Tags: python

I'm new to python and I'm still learning. It took me a couple of hours but I figured out how to do functions, however I am having a hard time allowing the user to enter how many they would like to enter. The outputs only work once, I'm sure it's because the for loop is broken into two functions but I can't seem to figure out whether the for loop only goes into the load and if so would that effect def calc(): ?

```
  def main():
    num_stocks,name,numsh,pp,sp,comm=load()
    Amtpaid,bycomm,stocksold,scomm,profit=calc(num_stocks,name,numsh,pp,sp,comm)
    prnt(Amtpaid,bycomm,stocksold,scomm,profit)

def load():
    #load inputs
    num_stocks=int(input("How many stocks do you want processed?"))
    for i in range (num_stocks):
        print("Stock number",i+1)
        print(".....................")
        name=input("Enter stock name:\n")
        numsh=float(input("Number of Shares:\n"))
        pp=float(input("Enter Purchase Price:\n"))
        sp=float(input("Enter Selling Price:\n"))
        comm=float(input("Enter Commission:\n"))
        print("Stock Results",end='')
        print("..................")
        return  num_stocks,name,numsh,pp,sp,comm

def calc(num_stocks,name,numsh,pp,sp,comm):
    #calculations
    for d in range (num_stocks):
        Amtpaid=numsh*pp
        bycomm=Amtpaid*comm
        stocksold=numsh*sp
        scomm=stocksold*comm
        profit=(Amtpaid+comm)-(scomm-comm)
        return Amtpaid,bycomm,stocksold,scomm,profit

def prnt(Amtpaid,bycomm,stocksold,scomm,profit):
    #print outputs
    print("Amount paid for stock:$",format(Amtpaid,',.2f'))
    print("Commision paid on the purchase:$",format(bycomm,',.2f'))
    print("Amount the stock sold for:$:",format(stocksold,',.2f'))
    print("Commission paid on the sale:$",format(scomm,',.2f'))
    print("Profit:$",format(profit,',.2f'))
    print("\n")


main()
```

Comment: Could you paste your code here? Please don't just give a image.

Comment: It is bad to just post a link to your code. You should directly write it directly here.

Comment: Do you want to enter all the input first then print all the output; or do you want to enter the input for one stock, print the output for that stock, enter the input for the next stock, and so on?

Answer (score 0):

In your for loop:

```
for d in range(num_stucks):
       #todo
       prnt(a, b, c, d, e, f)
```

Because when you run loop once, you return the value, so it will break the loop.

Comment: So instead of doing return I would replace it with the following function in this case I would use prnt()?

Comment: And that would be inside of the for loop or would it have to be outside?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the `return` statement that you have applied inside the `for` loop in `load` function.

bring it outside of the loop. If you want to call other functions, call them inside loop. like in your case call `call` function(that you are calling in `main`) instead of return statement

```
def main():
    num_stocks,name,numsh,pp,sp,comm=load()


def load():
    #load inputs
    num_stocks=int(input("How many stocks do you want processed?"))
    for i in range (num_stocks):
        print("Stock number",i+1)
        print(".....................")
        name=input("Enter stock name:\n")
        numsh=float(input("Number of Shares:\n"))
        pp=float(input("Enter Purchase Price:\n"))
        sp=float(input("Enter Selling Price:\n"))
        comm=float(input("Enter Commission:\n"))
        print("Stock Results",end='')
        print("..................")
        calc(num_stocks,name,numsh,pp,sp,comm)

def calc(num_stocks,name,numsh,pp,sp,comm):
    #calculations
    for d in range (num_stocks):
        Amtpaid=numsh*pp
        bycomm=Amtpaid*comm
        stocksold=numsh*sp
        scomm=stocksold*comm
        profit=(Amtpaid+comm)-(scomm-comm)
        prnt(Amtpaid,bycomm,stocksold,scomm,profit)

def prnt(Amtpaid,bycomm,stocksold,scomm,profit):
    #print outputs
    print("Amount paid for stock:$",format(Amtpaid,',.2f'))
    print("Commision paid on the purchase:$",format(bycomm,',.2f'))
    print("Amount the stock sold for:$:",format(stocksold,',.2f'))
    print("Commission paid on the sale:$",format(scomm,',.2f'))
    print("Profit:$",format(profit,',.2f'))
    print("\n")


main()
```

This is the solution.

Comment: So would I have to replace the return statement with a print statement?

Comment: no . instead of print use "Amtpaid,bycomm,stocksold,scomm,profit=calc(num_stocks,name,numsh,pp,sp,comm)"

Answer (score 0):

I'd just have a single `for` loop in `main()` that drove the series of calls to the functions you've defined to process each transaction. Congratulations on not using global variables, which is probably the number one mistake I see newbies make.

I also strongly suggest you start leaning (and following) the [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) and using more whitespace, which is your friend because it makes your code so much more readable.

```
def main():
    num_stocks = int(input("How many stocks do you want processed?"))
    for stock_number in range(1, num_stocks+1):
        name, numsh, pp, sp, comm = load(stock_number)
        amtpaid, bycomm, stocksold, scomm, profit = calc(name, numsh, pp, sp,
                                                         comm)
        prnt(amtpaid, bycomm, stocksold, scomm, profit)

def load(stock_number):
    # load inputs for one transaction
    print("Stock number", stock_number)
    print(".....................")
    name = input("Enter stock name:\n")
    numsh = float(input("Number of Shares:\n"))
    pp = float(input("Enter Purchase Price:\n"))
    sp = float(input("Enter Selling Price:\n"))
    comm = float(input("Enter Commission:\n"))
    print("Stock Results", end='')
    print("..................")
    return name, numsh, pp, sp, comm

def calc(name, numsh, pp, sp, comm):
    # calculations for one transaction
    amtpaid = numsh*pp
    bycomm = amtpaid*comm
    stocksold = numsh*sp
    scomm = stocksold*comm
    profit = (amtpaid+comm) - (scomm-comm)
    return amtpaid, bycomm, stocksold, scomm, profit

def prnt(amtpaid, bycomm, stocksold, scomm, profit):
    # print output for one transaction
    print("Amount paid for stock: ${:,.2f}".format(amtpaid))
    print("Commision paid on the purchase: ${:,.2f}".format(bycomm))
    print("Amount the stock sold for: ${:,.2f}".format(stocksold))
    print("Commission paid on the sale: ${:,.2f}".format(scomm))
    print("Profit: ${:,.2f}".format(profit))
    print("\n")

main()
```